# Android canvas not drawing on rtl

Tags: android, canvas, right-to-left

I have the following view class:

```
public class MyHorizontalViewIndicator extends View{

     protected synchronized void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
           super.onDraw(canvas);
           Paint paint = new Paint();
           paint.setTextSize(30);
           canvas.drawText("Test",90, 90, paint);
     }
}



 <com.my.myview.MyHorizontalViewIndicator
    android:id="@+id/view_indicator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layoutDirection="inherit"/>
```

When the language is English, (LTR) the test message appears fine, however, when I change the language to Arabic (RTL) the canvas is not shown.

[image: LTR]

[image: RTL]

Answer (score 0):

In Manifest.xml have you added `android:supportsRtl`

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Change this line `canvas.drawText("Test",90, 90, paint);` to

```
canvas.drawText("Test",bound.top-100, bound.left-100, paint);
```

try the negative value for the drawtext

and also change and try the layoutDirection=LOCALE in xml

Answer (score 0):

you can add this code :

```
 layoutDirection = LayoutDirection.LTR
```

Comment: I've meant to explain it in your answer... You can edit it anytime!

Comment: @fzs this is a layout direction to the view the superclass of the view in general handle it but when you build your own view you need to handle it by yourself. what this code is to force the draw view to b exactly like English Local (from left to right).

in general, this issue happens when you support language that starts righting from right to left such as Arabic