# Android canvas not showing on rtl

Tags: android, canvas, android-recyclerview, item-decoration

I'm using this code to draw circles and vertical lines on RecyclerView:

```
    @Override
    public void onDrawOver(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        int itemCount = parent.getAdapter().getItemCount();
        final int left = (int) (parent.getPaddingLeft() + (10 * DP));

        for (int i = 0; i <= itemCount; i++) {
            final View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
            if (child == null) { 
                continue;
            }

            final RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
            final int top = child.getTop() + params.topMargin;
            final int bottom = child.getBottom();

            if (i != itemCount-1){
                drawVerticalLine(c,left,top+circleRadius*2+circleStroke,left,bottom-circleStroke);
            }

            drawCircle(c, left + child.getPaddingLeft(), top + circleRadius , circleRadius);


        }
        super.onDrawOver(c, parent, state);
```

and it should be something like:

o item1
|
|
o item2
|
|
o item3
..etc

when the language is LTR language it's working fine but when i change the language to RTL language the canvas is not showing

Comment: take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46928929/android-canvas-not-drawing-on-rtl

Comment: @Mr.Patel it's not answered